# load external JavaScript file to chrome as a content script in manifest

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I'd like to ask a really quick question.
Is it possible to do what I have stated in the title?

I've been researching for a couple of hours now, and it keeps giving me all these content script yada yada but It doesn't seem to work.

I have JavascriptA at https://Mydomain.com/JavascriptA

and would like to load it as a content script in my chrome extension's manifest.